# How the Latent Dirichlet Allocation (LDA) algorithm work in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mahout, lda

I wonder if someone could briefly explain me the details of the LDA algorithm in Mahout. How the TF-IDF vector is used and what happens in each iteration. I need to understand the memory requirement in the mapper and reducer